# Error while installing DBeaver On Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, java, mysql, openjdk, database

I am trying to install `Dbeaver 3.5.6` on Ubuntu `14.04`, but it shows some Java run-time missing error even though I've Java7 installed on my system.

Here's how I tried to install

1. `user@Demo:~/Downloads$ wget http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/files/3.5.6/dbeaver-ce_3.5.6_i386.deb`
2. `user@Demo:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i dbeaver-ce_3.5.6_i386.deb`

and it throws an error like this

```
(Reading database ... 170900 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack dbeaver-ce_3.5.6_i386.deb ...
Unpacking dbeaver-ce (3.5.6) over (3.5.6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dbeaver-ce:
 dbeaver-ce depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless | openjdk-8-jre-headless | java-runtime-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-7-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package java-runtime-headless is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package dbeaver-ce (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dbeaver-ce
```

I am sure that the java installed on my system.

```
user@Demo:~/Downloads$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I think `DBeaver` need `openjdk` instead of normal `oracle_jdk`, isn't ?

How can I fix this problem ?

1. Should I install `openjdk` too ?
2. Can `openjdk` and normal `oracle jdk` work simultaneously in one system ?
3. Is there any alternative tool for DBeaver in Ubuntu. (I mean, which is the best one? ) ?

PS: am new in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue and this is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This installs dependencies and then finishes DBeaver.

Full script:

```
wget http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/files/dbeaver-ce_latest_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dbeaver-ce_latest_amd64.deb
rm dbeaver-ce_latest_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 3):

I use DBeaver on Ubuntu 14.04 as well. I never tried to install it as a deb package though--any particular reason you need to do that?

What I did was download the Linux zip archive from here:

http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/

Then you can just extract the contents to a folder, and run the dbeaver executable that's inside. It should "just work" with whatever your default JDK is, whether it's OpenJDK or Oracle. You can then create a shortcut/dock icon/whatever to that executable manually.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem.Though openjdk was installed in my system,Some how DBeaver was not able to recongnize by openjdk path.So After installing java-8-oracle I was able to use DBeaver.So try installing latest java version(either oracle or open jdk).Below is the java version present in my system.Installing java-8 solved my problem.

### Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status

0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081

Answer (score 0):

There is [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~serge-rider/+archive/ubuntu/dbeaver-ce) to install DBeaver on Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:serge-rider/dbeaver-ce
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dbeaver-ce
```

Answer (score 0):

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- Java Oracle 1.8.0_181-b13
- DBeaver 5.1.3 (16.07.2018)

## Installation

### Java

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

Attention: Other JDKs, like OpenJDK 7 and 8, didn't work for me!

### DBeaver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:serge-rider/dbeaver-ce
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dbeaver-ce
```

## Start

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ dbeaver
```

Yeah, error gone! :)